# How interpret the different testing accuracy values in Neural Network Toolbox in MATLAB?

Tags: matlab, neural-network

I am using Neural Network Toolbox [pattern recognition] for the classification of images.

Training - 70% of samples
Validation - 15%
Testing - 15%

On training, in some instances I get the accuracy as 100%. Some times as low as 30%.

So after retraining say for 10 times, which value we have to consider to say it as the classification accuracy? Average of accuracy values in all the training sessions?

Please let me know the correct approach.

Comment: Please explain (perhaps with a sample of output) which accuracy value you are talking about - train, cv or test (they should all be visible in a single run)? If the 30% to 100% variation is occurring on a single one of those (e.g. these are all cv accuracies), then something my be wrong, such as too few examples, too high learning rate etc. If you are mixing up between the different values, then it is possible to explain which one to use and why.

Comment: do you mean, that training data set checking give you precision 100% ?